# How can I make my custom model less shiny in Tabletop Simulator?

Tags: tabletop-simulator

I imported a model and UV map to Tabletop Simulator, but the model looks way too shiny. How can I make it less reflective like many of the models that I find on the Workshop?

Answer (score 1):

When importing the model, switch to the Material tab and choose the Wood or Cardboard preset:

[image]

If you've already imported the mode, you can change its settings by right clicking it and choosing Custom on the context menu:

[image]